# Can I pass a BuildContext to Compute?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

Is it possible to use BuildContext inside [compute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html) function?

```dart
Future<int> getFuture() async {
  int r = await compute(count, context);
  return r;
}

static int count(BuildContext context) {
  // Something very slow.
  return 10;
}
```

I receive the following error when attempting to pass the `context` to `compute`:

```
I/flutter ( 8764): AsyncSnapshot<int>(ConnectionState.done, null, Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a closure - Function '_handleBuildScheduled@374399801':.))
```

If I change the input to the count function to other normal class, it works fine.

Is there any way to fix this?
Or is using BuildContext possible in an [Isolate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/dart-isolate-library.html)?
Thanks!

Comment: the question is: why would you want to do that?

Comment: My code computes something complex using BuildContext.

Comment: so you have to change it so that it does not use `BuildContext`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [explained in the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html), no - you cannot send a `BuildContext` to a `compute` function, i.e. another `Isolate` (`compute` is only a wrapper for simple isolates).

> There are limitations on the values that can be sent and received to and from isolates. These limitations constrain the values of Q and R that are possible. See the discussion at [SendPort.send](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html).

The `message` is the value of `Q` (`R` is the return value) and is therefore subject to the following limitations:

> The content of `message` can be: primitive values (null, num, bool, double, String), instances of [SendPort](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/SendPort-class.html), and lists and maps whose elements are any of these. List and maps are also allowed to be cyclic.

---

If you want to learn more about isolates in general, the Flutter team published a [video about working with `Isolate`s in Flutter](https://youtu.be/qrFTt1NZed8). They also explain how isolates work on a lower level, which might be useful to you in understanding why these limitations are in place.